# Why characters are continuous?

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, analysis

A function $F$ from an abelian group $G$ to $S^1=\{z\in\mathbb{C}:|z|=1\}$ is called a character if $F(ab)=F(a)F(b)$ for all $a,b\in G$.

When $G=S^1$ so that $a=e^{ix_a},b=e^{ix_b}\in G$ with $ab:=e^{i(x_a+x_b)}$, it is said $F$ is continuous (with induced topology of $\mathbb{C}$ on $S^1$). I am wondering why?

It seems that we only need to show $F^{-1}(1)$ is a closed set in $S^1$. But how?

Comment: I strongly suspect that there are plenty of Abelian topological groups that have non-continuous characters...

Comment: I am wondering what happens to $G=S^1$? Are there any counterexamples?

Comment: I think for $G=S^1$ the only characters are z\to z^n$ for $n \in \Bbb Z$, IIRC.

Comment: I try to prove this fact. (This is Exercise 5 of Chapter 7 of Stein's Fourier Analysis Book.) But we need to know $F$ is continuous in this case first.

Comment: Are you asking why characters $S^1 \to \mathbb{C}^*$ are required to be continuous, how to prove that the ones you wrote are, or how to prove that $F^{-1}(1)\subset S^1$ is closed?

Comment: Just write down $F^{-1}(1)$ and show it's closed. What part of it are you stuck on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your book the concept of a character is introduced for *finite abelian groups* $G$ as a group homomorphism $G \to S^1$. See chapter 7.2.2.

However, in Example 2 the author says

> Example 2. The dual group of the circle is precisely $\{ e_n \}_{n \in \mathbb Z}$ (where $e_n(x) = e^{2\pi inx})$. Moreover, $e_n \mapsto n$ gives an isomorphism between $\hat{S^1}$ and the integers $\mathbb Z$.

This transcends the original definition since $S^1$ is not finite and in fact we find the following footnote:

> In addition to (2), the definition of a character on an infinite abelian group requires
>   continuity. When $G$ is the circle, $\mathbb R$, or $\mathbb R^+$, the meaning of "continuous" refers to the standard notion of limit.

Note that (2) is the definition of a character as a group homomorphism. Although the author does not say it explicitly, characters are usually defined as *continuous homomorphisms* $G \to S^1$ on a *topological* abelian group $G$. On a finite group one takes the discrete topology (which is the unique topology making $G$ a $T_0$-space).

There are certainly also discontinuous homomorphisms. See for example [Discontinuous group homomorphism from $(\mathbb{R},+)$ to $S^1$,unit circle](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1669578).